# Making every pixel of an image having a specific color transparent

Tags: java, image, transparency

This question is a duplicate of this question: 
[Making every pixel of an image having a specific color transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162007/making-every-pixel-of-an-image-having-a-specific-color-transparent)

But I need a Java equivalent. And I need a image-type (like `PNG`, `BMP`, ...) which can hold this color with full transparency (alpha = 0). And of course a way to save it as a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class Transparency {
  public static Image makeColorTransparent
    (Image im, final Color color) {
    ImageFilter filter = new RGBImageFilter() {
      // the color we are looking for... Alpha bits are set to opaque
      public int markerRGB = color.getRGB() | 0xFF000000;

      public final int filterRGB(int x, int y, int rgb) {
        if ( ( rgb | 0xFF000000 ) == markerRGB ) {
          // Mark the alpha bits as zero - transparent
          return 0x00FFFFFF & rgb;
          }
        else {
          // nothing to do
          return rgb;
          }
        }
      }; 

    ImageProducer ip = new FilteredImageSource(im.getSource(), filter);
    return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(ip);
    }
}
```

Modified the code to make each pixel transparent

Source :http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0265.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ImageIO.read`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.File%29) for reading a file and [`ImageIO.write`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) for writing. Use the `getRGB` and `setRGB` methods of [`BufferedImage`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) to change the colours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`LookupOp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/LookupOp.html) with a four-component `LookupTable` that sets the alpha component to zero for colors that match the background. Examples may be found in [*Using the Java 2D LookupOp Filter Class to Process Images*](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3654171/Using-the-Java-2D-LookupOp-Filter-Class-to-Process-Images.htm) and [*Image processing with Java 2D*](https://web.archive.org/web/20100126030254/http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-1998/jw-09-media.html).