# What is high performance for creating a TIF image from a background TIF and a foreground TIF in java

Tags: java, colors, set, overlay, tiff

I have two TIF files, one is background (overlay) and the other is foreground. The following code is currently used for combining two TIFs.

```
    // Background color of foreground image
    int w = Color.WHITE.getRGB();

    // Fill all pixels which are not background color
    for (int i = 0; i < foregroundImage.getWidth(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < foregroundImage.getHeight(); j++)
        {
            int x = foregroundImage.getRGB(i, j);
            if (x != w)
                backgroundImage.setRGB(i, j, x);
        }
    }
```

Is there any other way that has a better performance to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `Color.white` pixels transparent using `RGBImageFilter`, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4380790/230513), or `LookupOp`, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383798/230513). Then you can use the `AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER` rule to combine the images. [`AlphaCompositeDemo`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/composite) is an example that lets one explore the available modes, and there's related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7824225/230513). Of course, you'll need to profile both approaches to see which is faster.