# Changing the alpha property on all whitespace in an image

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have an image, that will have white pixels in and around other pixels, and i need all of the whitespace to be transparent. how would i process the image reasonably fast? (unsafe code perhaps? i dont know how to do that..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to similar question answered on Stackoverflow.

[Making every pixel of an image having a specific color transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162007/making-every-pixel-of-an-image-having-a-specific-color-transparent/162063#162063)

Answer (score 0):

[A post in this thread shows you how to access the pixeldata](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/14788-c%23-fast-acces-to-bitmap-pixels/)